# Count number of double occurrences in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following google sheet

[Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnJqW.png)

I need to count how many "Advanced leaders", "Advanced followers" "Intermediate leaders" and "Intermediate followers" there are. For this I tried to use the function `COUNTIFS`. For example, to count the number of advanced leaders I used  `COUNTIFS( H10:H70,"Advanced",G10:G70,"Leader")` but it gives me the wrong number of leaders (4 instead of 5). Also the others counts are wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It might be helpful for us to share a sample.

Comment: There is no reason except a spelling difference ... here is my own file (instead of yours to be able to troubleshoot) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wnVXHVsDpqtotvb1xkvmY4SgtbuMJlWAGfFpIHpmlBw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I suggest you try inserting the following formula into cell `B6` - `=query(G10:H70, "select G, count(G) group by G pivot H")`. If there is a spelling difference in your data - you will see it

Comment: thank you! the problem was that some of the entries had a space at the end of the word. Do you know how to avoid that?